# Coercing an object to a new, package-specific class

Tags: r

I have a list of three objects coming from the function iNEXT:::iNEXT. The output is a list of class "iNEXT":
[image]

I then want to subset this list:

```
april <- list(out.all[[1]][1:59,], out.all[[2]][1:59], out.all[[3]][1:177,])
```

which creates a list with the same types of objects, but which losts the class "iNEXT":
[image]

Any subsequent functions created for objects of class "iNEXT" then fail, e.g.:

```
ggiNEXT(april, ...)
Error: iNEXT doesn't know how to deal with data of class list
```

. I tried to coerce `april` to the class iNEXT with `as()`

```
> as(april, iNEXT)
Error in is(object, Class) : 
  trying to get slot "className" from an object of a basic class ("function") with no slots
> as(april, "iNEXT")
Error in as(april, "iNEXT") : 
  keine Methode und kein Standard um “list” in “iNEXT” umzuwandeln
```

*(german for no "method or default for coercing “list” to “iNEXT”)*

Is there a way to do that? I couldnt even figure out what properties objects of class "iNEXT" have. Sorry for not posting a reproducible example, which would be very difficult in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out by looking into the function iNEXT:::INEXT.

```
class(april) <- c("iNEXT")
```

is required.
I leave that here if someone else might encounter the same problem.